# Which is the right screws to use to mount ikea pegboard to studs for heavy weights with noob skills?

Tags: studs, pegboard

I am super confused and overwhelmed with the amount of  research I have done so pardon the post that may seem like a duplicate but I need help in specifically this context.

Problem Statement : I want to mount ikea pegboard 30"x22" onto studs. I used a stud finder to determine that my studs are 24" apart. The house is less than 4 months old so I am confused why they didn't follow the 16" standard.

The pegboard of 30"x22" comes with a bar that has holes at 23-5/8". Hence, I think I can mount it directly to the studs. I am making this for mountaineering gear so I want it to be super sturdy and hold good amount of weight.

Screw length : 
I saw 3 inches being recommended most often so I was going to go with 3-1/2" screws just for safety. Is this okay? I just have regular drywall.

I shortlisted :

1. Structural Screws
   All forums kept recommending this and I felt that it applies to my use case. But when I search structural screws on home depot they are not very cheap or many models. Everything is 5lb pack but I only need maybe 10 of those.
   This looks strong, is affordable. The top shaft looks unusual, Am I going to need anything special to drive this in? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-3-in-Strong-Drive-SDS-Structural-Wood-Screws-25-Pack-SDS25300-R25/203302236

This looks strong and easily drivable but is expensive. Is it worth the price. https://www.homedepot.com/p/GRK-Fasteners-5-16-in-x-3-1-8-in-Rugged-Structural-Screw-45-Piece-Pack-112221/203533461

2. Cabinet screws

SPAX cabinet screw seems expensive :    https://www.homedepot.com/p/SPAX-10-x-2-1-2-in-T-Star-Drive-Washer-Wafer-Head-Partial-Thread-Yellow-Zinc-Coated-Cabinet-Screw-75-per-Box-4281020050606/206870578

Generic cabinet screw is cheaper but is it going to compromise the strength value. https://www.homedepot.com/p/10-x-3-in-Zinc-Plated-Truss-Head-Phillips-Drive-Cabinet-Screw-25-Pieces-803002/204275480

3. lagbolts : strong but overkill for my project. Harder for a noob like me because of predrilling need

Comment: all those screws are available in single quantities at homedepot

Comment: @jsotola Ah thanks. Due to the coronavirus situation I cant go in store right now but can only do pick up. I can find the single quantity on the website but I will try again. Otherwise I think this project will have to wait.

Comment: Just use 1/4" lag screws, you are over-complicating this. Yes you need to drill a pilot hole.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of the weight of the whole construction, once loaded?  The fasteners will be subject mostly to shear load, so you're looking at diameter more than length (which obviously does help against pull-out, but not as much as sheer diameter).

Comment: Your use of the dimension tag like 24' suggests that your studs are 24 feet apart. I think you really meant to use 24". It also seems to make your pegboard a more reasonable size because when I first saw this I wondered at a 22 foot long pegboard. I will edit your question to change these dimension indicators.

Comment: Thank you for fixing that for me Michael. Really appreciate it.

Comment: For weight of the total load it is hard to say but I would say 100lbs maximum per pegboard. I am considering situations like where we have cascading equipment like ice axes on the same one. There will also be a lot of movement with removing and keeping them.

Answer (score 1):

Your studs are probably 2x6 to get the thickness for the latest higher level of insulation which requires more wall depth. Since the studs can bear more load, they can be spaced at 24" oc rather than 16" oc.

All of those screws would work. Most of your forces on the screws will be in shear, not withdrawal, so the screw only needs to go deep enough to engage the strength of the steel and bearing of the wood, rather than getting a lot of tread into the studs for withdrawal.

I would use the SDS screws at about 2-1/2" which will give 2" of embed with 1/2" drywall. They will support over 340 lb each and therefore the peg board will be the weak point. Add as many as needed, say 1 per 100 lb of gear, and a minimum of four. I suggest predrilling pilot holes for ease of insulation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different wood screws that would work for this application. However, I'm partial to [Timberlok](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/fe5ab351-3bc8-46c0-8b79-37c75f9aa127/svn/fastenmaster-wood-screws-fmtlok212-50-64_1000.jpg) only because I've used them so many times in this type of application and they've never failed me. They are pricey but you can buy them in small quantities. One of the pluses I like is no predrilling is required and the shear strength is amazing for the diameter of the fastener.

Comment: I still pre-drill pilot holes for Timberlok fasteners. Doing so will prevent splitting and makes the fasteners  hold power even more than without drilling. I recently built a gate frame out of cedar 2x4s that were joined flat so I used 6" Timberloks through one 2x4 (3.5 inches) and into the end grain of the other. Two fasteners per joint. The  frame included cross braces in both directions to allow for plenty of support surface to nail the cedar boards onto the front for the gate. The frame with the Timberloks is amazingly strong and solid. Spendy fasteners but awesome product.

Comment: For my use case will they still need to be 2.5" length. I am going with the recommendation of the SDS screw length.

Comment: SDS is good but fyi Timberlok makes a 2.5".